# Jquery Cycle2 Link Inside Pager Area Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, jquery-cycle2

I've got a setup working with the cycle2 plugin, but the link inside the pager area doesn't work, unless you right-click it and 'open in new window'. Suggestions?

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx=fade data-cycle-timeout=50000 data-cycle-pager="#no-template-pager" data-cycle-slides="div" data-cycle-pager-template="">
<div id="tab1"><h1>Test Slide One</h1></div>
<div id="tab2"><h1>Test Slide Two</h1></div>
<div id="tab3"><h1>Test Side Three</h1></div>
<div id="tab4"><h1>Test Slide Four</h1></div> 
</div>
<div id="no-template-pager">
<div class="tab1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><p><a href="http://www.google.com">Test Link</a></p> </div>

<div class="tab2"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><p><a href="http://www.google.com">Test Link</a></p> </div>

<div class="tab3"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><p><a href="http://www.google.com">Test Link</a></p> </div>

<div class="tab4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><p><a href="http://www.google.com">Test Link</a></p> </div>
</div>
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gandjyar/FKBYm/1/), notice clicking the link in the pager area does nothing, but if you right-click it, the link opens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the cycle2 too and had the same problem but it was resolved adding data-cyle-pager-eventbubble="true" or in my case pagerEventBubble: true. It bubbles the event click on DOM allowing the href to be seen and executed.

i'm using jquery 1.9.1, and the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.banner-imagem').cycle({
    slides: "li",
    timeout: 0,
    fx: "fadeout",
    speed: 400,
    manualFx: "scrollHorz",
    manualSpeed: 400,
    pager: "#banner-nav",
    pagerTemplate: "#per-slide-template",
    loader: "wait",
    log: false,
    pagerActiveClass: "slide-ativo",
    slideActiveClass: "slide-ativo",
    slideClass: "slide-imagem",
    pagerEventBubble: true
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use stopPropagation on link when you click, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#no-template-pager a').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```